# React Yarn build fails with unexpected behaviour

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-2

While running a yarn build, an infinite loop was induced with below warning:

> (node:7424) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
>   parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
>
> Warning, the following targets are using a decimal version:
>
> node: 6.5
>
> We recommend using a string for minor/patch versions to avoid numbers like 6.10
>   getting parsed as 6.1, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

Error screenshot:

[image]

If you need any file/code, please comment - I'll add them. I couldn't understand the issue, so I did not include any code.

[Package.JSON](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lcILcYI8ktyBiDynhoBJBYueqfV1eBl-)

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 0):

Without your `package.json` it's hard to tell where exactly the problem is.

If your version for your package (or any of the dependencies) isn't using a semantic versioning (for example 6.10.0 instead of just 6.10 which might get trimmed to 6.1) then that is what is causing the problem.

When the error mentions minor/patch it is referring to the numbers separated by dots/periods

..

More about this can be found here: https://semver.org/

and here https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with my package.json. you can check that

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that was the problem. 
Check the section for `engines`

Change the `6.5` to something like `6.5.0` same goes for npm `3.10` to `3.10.0`
If you need to ensure its 6.5 you can add the tilde `~` which says you can have 6.5 plus any patches (6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2... 6.5.n)


```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.5",
    "npm": ">=3.10"
  },
```